# Allow 1000+ concurrent users on IIS 8 for ASP.NET MVC web application

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, iis-8

We have built the ASP.NET MVC4 application and deployed on IIS8.5
We updated setting in Appication pool for QueueLength = 5000 and also updated the same in ASP.NET.config file of framework (C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319)[Appication pool setting upate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mj4MA.png)

[ASP.NET Config file change](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RrWwj.png)

Still, max 100 users are allowed in one go and rest being queued.
Server configuration is 4 core  processor, 8 GB Ram and 64-bit OS.

Need help to fix my problem. many many thanks in Advance.
Attached image of all configuration.

We updated setting in Appication pool for QueueLength = 5000 and also updated the same in ASP.NET.config file of framework (C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319)

Allow maximum number of users with concurrent login and support.[SServer Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tjT12.png)

Comment: Could you please tell me the version of your server? 2012 or 2008? Beisdes, I suggest you could also run below command to modify the appConcurrentRequestLimit in server runtime in applicationhost.config file.  c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe set config /section:serverRuntime /appConcurrentRequestLimit:100000

Comment: MY server is window server 2012 R2.

Comment: Thank you @BrandoZhang for swift reply. We have tried and it worked like a charm.However,I would like a recommendation from you regarding two options we have.
1 We can Update my existing server from 4 Core 8gb RAM to 6 core 16 GB RAM or 
2 We can Keep separate servers i.e One for IIS and One  for SQL Server. Server Config will be same for both(4 Core 8GB RAM).
Which option would be preferable?   
Thanks In advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Need help to fix my problem. many many thanks in Advance. Attached image of all configuration.

I suggest you could   run below command to modify the appConcurrentRequestLimit in server runtime in applicationhost.config file.

```
 c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe set config /section:serverRuntime /appConcurrentRequestLimit:100000
```

> However,I would like a recommendation from you regarding two options we have. 1 We can Update my existing server from 4 Core 8gb RAM to 6 core 16 GB RAM or 2 We can Keep separate servers i.e One for IIS and One for SQL Server. Server Config will be same for both(4 Core 8GB RAM). Which option would be preferable?

In my opinion, this should according to your application performance. I think you should analysis the sql's performance, if you find the sql has takes a lot of server's resource to handle the sql query or something elese which cause your IIS takes so long time to response, I suggest you could keep separate servers.

If you find the sql server just take a little server resouce, I suggest you could use use just one server.

Comment: Thank you very much once again for your valuable suggestions. We are going for different server, as we have other Applications Db on same SQL server.